# Multiple data set plotting with a break in the y-axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am able to plot Multiple data sets in a single plot and a plot with a single data set with a break in the y-axis([This page helped me](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)) separately. But What I would like to do is to remove the portion from 10^46 to 10^58 in the following plot.![image] The code which I used to plot is

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Computer Modern']})

x_1=np.linspace(5e13, 8e14, 201)
z = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 201)
y_1 =np.cos(z)*1e43
x_2=np.linspace(5e13, 1e15, 201)
y_2 =np.cos(z)*1e61
x_3=np.linspace(3e13, 1e15, 201)
y_3 =np.tan(z)*1e63

run_1,=plt.plot(x_1, y_1, '.b') 
run_2,=plt.plot(x_2, y_2, '.g') 
run_3,=plt.plot(x_3, y_3,'.r') 

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim([40000000000000,2000000000000000])


plt.legend((run_1, run_2,run_3), ('CR Flux','Gas Ensrgy','Total Energy'),scatterpoints=1, loc='lower right', ncol=1, fontsize=12)

# Turn on a grid
grid(True)
savefig('camp_line.png')
show()
```

How to achieve this? Is there any function for achieving this?

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code here?

Comment: Does this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html not work for you?  Also, could you please edit your example so others could run it (ie, generate some fake but appropriate data instead of reading files, eg, `x=np.linspace(5e13, 8e14, 1000); y=1e43+10*sin(x)`).

Comment: @tom10 as you suggested I edited the program. The example matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html is not working  for me.

Comment: @tcaswell the amount of code has been reduced.

Comment: @RSJohn: why isn't the example working for you?

Comment: @tom10 sorry for the delay in  reply. I was bedridden due to fever.The  example 'matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html' is not working for multiple data set.